# Fundamental of a signal

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions, harmonic-analysis, periodic-functions

Consider the space $S$ of real functions with the norm $$\|f\|^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} f^2(x) ~\mathrm{d}x, $$

or any reasonable Euclidean norm such that bounded functions have a finite norm.

Can we construct a continuous function mapping from $S$ to the space of distributions over $\mathbb{R}$ such that periodic functions of period $\tau$ are mapped to $\delta_{\tau}$?

The motivation is to define some reasonable notion of the fundamental of a signal.

Comment: Make a sequence of functions of period $\pi$ whose limit is of period $2\pi$. Your map is discontinuous.

Comment: Seems like it indeed. Happy to accept as an answer or, alternatively delete the question.

Comment: @BenMcKay: You probably meant it the other way around? (A pointwise limit of functions of period $p$ has period $p$ or smaller.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling: yes, of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sequence of functions of period $2\pi$ whose limit is of period $\pi$. Your map is discontinuous.